# timer.performWithDelay running immediately

Tags: wordpress, lua

Simple question: can anyone tell me why the createBalloon function runs immediately?

```
makeBalloonfromRainbow = timer.performWithDelay(5000, createBalloon(x, y), 1)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
makeBalloonfromRainbow = timer.performWithDelay(5000, function() createBalloon(x, y) end, 1)
```